# Providing Prometheus metrics in a custom KafkaConnect plugin

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I'm running a custom KafkaConnect source connector plugin in a Strimzi k8s cluster and want to provide metrics to Prometheus.
The most simple approach would be to expose an [http server](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#http) to expose the metrics, but I'm running into the issue that I can't expose the http server's port in strimzi as its configuration (0.35.1) doesn't allow that (see also [crd definition](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/0.35.1/install/cluster-operator/041-Crd-kafkaconnect.yaml)).

I'm aware I could also use a [pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#exporting-to-a-pushgateway), but am wondering if there is another more straightfoward approach for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose Prometheus metrics directly through Strimzi. Please check the docs and the examples. That can expose also connector metrics if they expose them through JMX as Kafka Connect itself does.